# JavaScript binding loss with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, closure

My current task is to extend some JavaScript of a framework we are using. A pop-up should slide in, instead of just appear in the middle of the window.
So I have overridden one of the framework's methods, and do at the end this:

```
AdfDhtmlPage.prototype.showMessages = function (componentId) {

// Some code here

function slideIn() {
  var maxTop = windowHeight - (thisHeight + 18);
  var tempTop = parseInt(popupElement._rootElement.style.top);

  if (maxTop >= tempTop) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      AdfPage.PAGE.clearMessages(componentId);
    },5000);
    return;
  }

  popupElement._rootElement.style.top = tempTop - 1 + 'px';
  setTimeout(slideIn, 20);
}
slideIn();
}
```

Everything worked just fine, but then I thought that the `slideIn` method should somehow be a behavior of the `popupElement`.
During refactoring I encountered a behavior that was new to me and which is [here](http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations) called *binding loss*.
So what I came up with is this:

```
AdfDhtmlPage.prototype.showMessages = function (componentId) {
    // Some code here
    popupElement._slideIn(popupElement, componentId);
}

AdfDhtmlSimpleFloat.prototype._slideIn = function(element, componentId) {
    var maxTop = AdfAgent.AGENT.getWindowHeight() - (element.getHeight() + 18);
    var thisTop = parseInt(element._rootElement.style.top);

    if (maxTop >= thisTop) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            AdfPage.PAGE.clearMessages(componentId);
        },5000);
        return;
    }

    element._rootElement.style.top = thisTop - 1 + 'px';
    setTimeout(function() {
        element._slideIn(element, componentId);
    }, 20);
}
```

So when calling the `_slideIn` method of `popupElement` I need to pass `popupElement` as argument. So I can access the objects properties, after the method has been called via `setTimeout` (When the binding loss happens).

However, this seems odd to me. So I would like to ask you to review my design. Maybe someone comes up with a better solution?

---

that was, what I wanted to do:

```
AdfDhtmlPage.prototype.showMessages = function (componentId) {
    // Some code here
    popupElement._slideIn(componentId);
}

AdfDhtmlSimpleFloat.prototype._slideIn = function(componentId) {
    var maxTop = AdfAgent.AGENT.getWindowHeight() - (this.getHeight() + 18);
    var thisTop = parseInt(this._rootElement.style.top);

    if (maxTop >= thisTop) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            AdfPage.PAGE.clearMessages(componentId);
        },5000);
        return;
    }

    this._rootElement.style.top = thisTop - 1 + 'px';
    setTimeout(this._slideIn, 20);
}
```

Comment: Why would you assume that your element should be bound inside the AdfDhtmlSimpleFloat object? (is popupElement an AdfDhtmlSimpleFloat?). I notice from the ADF docs that they warn you not to use these classes at all, are you sure you want to?

Comment: Yes the `popupElement` is an `AdfDhtmlSimpleFloat` object. We are aware of the possible draw-backs of using their classes, but didn't see any other way.

Comment: Can you post the broken code? You should not be passing in a reference to the Object explicitly as you are. I suspect that you were missing the `this` for example `this._rootElement.style.top`.

Comment: OK, did you update the `AdfDhtmlSimpleFloat` prototype before trying to call the function? Here is a super simple example http://jsfiddle.net/yvJfw/2/, comment and uncomment the calls to updateElem to see.

Comment: Yes, the function is defined, and gets called properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this._slideIn` refers to a function, not a method invocation.  In your third code sample, changing your last line to

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() { self._slideIn(componentId) }, 20);
```

should be sufficient.  You have to capture `this` in the closure that you pass to `setTimeout()`, because when the code runs later, `this` will refer to something else in that execution context.

Comment: This did it. Could you please elaborate on this? I debugged it and don't understand it. Now at every call, `this` references the `AdfDhtmlSimpleFloat` object. Why is this so?

Comment: You would be better off taking this up on StackOverflow.  Here's the [background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429) and a [reformulation of your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241).